# how to run facebook login in localhost using codeigniter

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-login

I used the facebook sdk for codeigniter to put its login on my website. I am trying to run the code but I am getting error. I am running it on my localhost providing the localhost url on facebook's site_url and i have tried to follow the instructions it has provided. THe error I am getting is
`Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\Facebook' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\huebind\application\libraries\facebook.php on line 67`

The problem must be with not installing with composer. Unfortunately I dont know how to do it either.  I simply copied the code on my codeigniter. What difference does it make?

Comment: Please do not post a picture of the error message.  Include the actual text so it's easier to read and searchable in the SO database.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear... you do not have a `Facebook` class at the indicated location.  You're also going to have to show us the relevant code.

Comment: Did you read the helpful comments in the top of the `Facebook.php` file?  *"This library requires the Facebook PHP SDK to be installed with Composer..."*

Comment: what difference does it make? How do i install it using composer? @Sparky

Comment: Apparently it makes a huge difference because the `Facebook` Class is missing as per your error message.  Go to [the documentation on this page](https://github.com/darkwhispering/facebook-sdk-codeigniter) and look at [the "Read More" link in Step 5](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted#install-composer).

Comment: how do i install the facebook sdk on the codeigniter if i already have installed composer? @sparky

Comment: Based on your OP and the comments, I really have no idea what you've done.  You have not even described which steps were followed/skipped as per the documentation you linked.  Please use the "edit" link to fix your question as per this page:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install the composer and put the composer.json file inside the application folder. then from the directory use composer install from command prompt. It will work